# Recover corrupt bytea column

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres database with a bytea column with corrupt data.  I have recovered an old backup to a different machine and can see this data is not corrupt as per below.  When I compare the results on corrupt vs recovered the values are different.

```
SELECT recordid,encode(secretkey::bytea, 'hex') FROM table;
```

I would just like to know the best way export the bytea column from the recovered table to the corrupt table so the data transfers exactly as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/contrib-dblink-function.html) to connect to your recovery server and update your `secretkey` joining by the `recordid`. On the corrupted DB server you would execute:

```
UPDATE table SET
  secretkey = t.secretkey
FROM
  dblink(
    'host=your.host dbname=recoverydb...',
    'SELECT recordid, secretkey FROM table'
  ) t(recordid integer, secretkey bytea)
WHERE
  recordid = t.recordid
```

You could use [foreign data wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/postgres-fdw.html) instead of dblink to access recovered data.

You could backup your `table` and then restore it to your DB with name `table_recovered` and use it in the `FROM` part of the update statement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this information.  I assumed you could run a query accross multiple databases if they were within the same PSQL instance but apparantly not so dblink has helped me alot.  I ended up backing the working table and recovering it to the production PSQL instance as mm_backup and performing the below for reference.

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
UPDATE mediarecords 
SET secretkey = T1.secretkey
FROM dblink('host=localhost user=xxxxx password=xxxxx dbname=mm_backup',
    'SELECT recordid, secretkey FROM mediarecords'
  ) AS T1(recordid integer, secretkey bytea)
WHERE
mediarecords.recordid = T1.recordid;
```